# Why is the "webpage is slowing down" occuring on using a while loop with a setTimeout in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, math

I made this component in React with a while loop which has a  setTimeout inside it. It is causing the browser to stop responding and I get "webpage is slowing down" in Firefox developers browser and in chrome too. What is the possible reason? Here is the code:-

```
class Adbanner extends React.Component{

changer() {

        var i=0;  
        while(i>=0 && i<4){ 
          setTimeout(function(){
             document.getElementById('ad').src=adarray[i];
             i++; 
          }, 2000);            

        }     
}

    render() {
    return (
       <div>
            <input id="ad" type="image" src={ad2} style={{position:'absolute',height:'50%',width:'100%'}}></input>      
          {setInterval(this.changer, 2000)}  
       </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Adbanner;
```

How to solve it?

Comment: The setInterval function will only run when the current function reaches the end. Since you are increasing `i`inside it, it will never change value and your while loop will run forever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var i=0;  
while(i>=0 && i<4){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('ad').src=adarray[i];
  i++; 
}, 2000);
}
```

The `setTimeout` does not wait to be complete. `setTimeout` sends the function to a different data structure and keeps going through the code. It just keeps cycling repeatedly as fast as computationally possible. Try doing this:

```
var i=0;  
while(i>=0 && i<4){ 
  setTimeout(function(){
  document.getElementById('ad').src=adarray[i];
  i++; 
}, 2000);
console.log('created a setTimeout')
}
```

It looks like you're trying to run the function 4 times, while waiting for 2000ms each run. `setInterval` with a `clearInterval` condition would be perfect for your needs

```
function changer() {
  var i=0;  
  let imageChange = setInterval(() => {
    if (i < 4) {
      document.getElementById('ad').src=adarray[i];
      i++
    } else {
      clearInterval(imageChange)
    }
  }, 2000)
}
```

Comment: this gave me the closest results so far ...but it only iterates 4 times ...but I want it to repeat infinitely...actually i AM trying to make an AD-Banner so ..I want the images to change again and again...how to do it

Comment: k did it thanks a lot >....put the function call within componentdidmount and and used another if inside the if and changed i to 0 if i==4.... thanks:)

Comment: @J.Doe Always happy to help. Happy coding

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to call `setInterval` inside your render function. Render is supposed to be free of side-effects. What is happening is that any time the component, or its parent changes, render is getting called. That means your interval is getting created possibly many times.

Instead, move the setInterval to `componentDidMount()`

Additionally, in your setInterval, you are creating 4 setTimeout calls. So, every 2 seconds, you will update the `ad` table 4 times. That doesn't seem to be exactly what your desire is.

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in this code-

1. *document.getElementById* is not a valid way to change attributes in React.
2. You are executing *setInterval* in render method. Now Imagine what's happening- the first time render is called *setInterval* is executed and then four *setTimeout* methods are being called. Upon the execution of first timeout render is getting called again which fires a new *setInterval* eventually. This is causing an infinite loop of *setInterval* and *render*.

You should use a *commit phase lifecycle method* for setinterval method like *componentDidMount* so that *setInterval* is called only once.

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loops until `i` is iterated 4 times. Now, `i` is iterated when  `setTimeout` executes the function given to it, BUT that function is only executed *after* 2 seconds. Meanwhile, `while` loops a zillion times.

You're not using the power of React, though! Check out this guide on the React website that teaches you how to do this exact scenario: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

e.g.

```
class Adbanner extends React.Component {

  // Set this component's state as the current ad index
  state = {ad: 0};

  // Rotates the ad index state every 2 seconds
  rotateAd () {
    this.setState({ad: (this.state.ad + 1) % adarray.length});
    this.timer = setTimeout(this.rotateAd, 2000);
  }

  // Start rotating the ad index when mounted
  componentDidMount () {
    this.rotateAd();
  }

  // Renders when constructed, then whenever the state changes (or when React wants to)
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input id="ad" type="image" src={adarray[this.state.ad]} style="position:absolute, height:50%, width:100%">
      </div>
    );
  }

  // Stop the update timer when unmounting
  componentWillUnmount () {
    clearTimeout(this.timer);
  }
}

export default Adbanner;
```

I haven't tested this. Let me know how it works out.